# Unable to enable AntiMalware for Azure Cloud Service (Classic)

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

We are trying to configure AntiMalware extensions for classic Azure Cloud Services by changing the service definition file (csdef). We know we can do this via powershell/portal, but we want this to be part of the definition so that re-deployments don't wipe out the config each time.

We've added the import entry:

```
<Import moduleName="AntiMalware" />
```

As well as the settings definitions:

```
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ServiceLocation" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableAntimalware" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableRealtimeProtection" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.EnableWeeklyScheduledScans" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.DayForWeeklyScheduledScans" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.TimeForWeeklyScheduledScans" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedExtensions" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedPaths" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Antimalware.ExcludedProcesses" />
```

But when I try to build/package the cloud service using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.2 and I get the following error:

> Unable to import module AntiMalware.  No manifest was found.

There seems to be virtually no documentation on this outside of very out dated blog posts. I'm wondering if the name of this module changed?

Comment: It appears you can also use a startup task. Ideally I'd rather do this using the CSDEF if possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configuration-and-management-faq#how-can-i-add-an-antimalware-extension-for-my-cloud-services-in-an-automated-way

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you provide the method in the link, use the definition and use the ps1 file to install `AntiMalware`.

Searching a lot of documents and materials, your needs should be achievable, and there are detailed steps in the 2012 official documents.

[Microsoft Endpoint Protection for Windows Azure Customer Technology Preview Now Available For Free Download](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/microsoft-endpoint-protection-for-windows-azure-customer-technology-preview-now-available-for-free-download/)

There are also blogs explaining about this `.csdef` file, using `<Import moduleName="AntiMalware" />`.

[How to Protect Against Malware on Windows Azure](https://dzone.com/articles/how-enable-anti-malware)

Suggestions, [raise a support ticket on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), and seek official final advice. Because this document is too old, I did not try it.